# Input Fields lagging in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner at frontend and not even sure if this is the right place to ask this question but a developer has created a react app and when data is thrown into the input field via a bluetooth device(like barcode scanner), it lags too much sometimes.

> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LFqGhp1HyEMnyzO16W8KlG8_tJcXTrOr?usp=sharing

The videos will help in better understanding of the problem. and the following is the code:

```
<Form.Item name="rfId" label="">
  <Input
    key={`input-${selectedSerialKey}`}
    disabled={!selectedWarehouse || status !== statusValues.start}
    placeholder="Enter RFID"
    value={currentSerialText}
    onChange={handleRFIDChange}
  />
</Form.Item>;
```

Is there any option where I dont show the scanned data being filled in the input field and show it directly to the table. I am thinking this might save the time. or if someone can guide me what topic should I search to tackle this?

```
const handleRFIDChange = (e) => {
  setCurrentSerialText(e.target.value);
};

const onAddSerial = (e) => {
  if (selectedSerialKeyRef.current !== null && findSerial) {
    setClearText((prev) => prev + 1);
    setSerials(
      serials.map((item) => {
        if (item.$key === selectedSerialKeyRef.current && findSerial) {
          return {
            ...item,
            serial: currentSerialTextRef.current,
          };
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      })
    );
    setSelectedSerialKey(null);
  } else {
    setClearText((prev) => prev + 1);
    setSerials((prev) =>
      removeDuplicateItems(
        [
          ...prev,
          { serial: currentSerialTextRef.current, $key: Math.random() },
        ],
        "serial"
      )
    );
  }
  forceRerender();
  // setCurrentSerialText('');
};
```

Comment: Can you share the code for handleRFIDChange

Comment: @Aneesh The form also check for duplicate values and shows only unique items in the table

Comment: im not seeing anything jump out at me from the raw component - it could be with how much memory the page is consuming, or how many components are loading prior to the input being loaded, if you have lots of modals and windows calculating prior to the input then it will definitely cause lag on lots of devices. Every change (everytime an input updates) causes the component to rebuild in the shadow dom

Comment: additionally, if you are updating state multiple times in one action rather than building your changes and updating state once, that can also do it

Comment: @alilland How can I check if the state is building multiple times ?

Comment: everywhere you are calling "set" you are updating state, you want to calculate whatever changes you are going to apply in memory first, then apply them at the end instead of as you go

Comment: @alilland Got it! Thanks! I'll surely check it but if I were to search and read in this topic what should be the ideal search term ?

Comment: I assume your app is using react hooks in order to update state, so getting a good understanding of those is probably the best starting point after understanding the react lifecycle